# Is this media "treasure hunt" acceptable?

Tags: discussion

I have a come up with a list of license plates from movies and TV shows. They all show prominently in the frame for enough time to be read easily. The solution to the "puzzle" is just a list of the shows and movies they come from.

I wonder if this is appropriate for the site, as it's not something you can deduce from logic or clues; it's just something you might have by your side while watching stuff and you might find some of them.

Comment: This seems like more *trivia* than puzzle to me - there's no aha moment to find, it's just "do you recognize this thing?". I feel like if this counted as a puzzle, then almost any sort of "identify this thing" question would, and that would be too broad of a scope for Puzzling.

Comment: I agree: I don't think this is puzzle-y enough to be a good fit for PSE. (Which isn't to say it mightn't be fun; but not all fun things belong here.)

Comment: (I think Deusovi has misunderstood one aspect of it. I don't think the idea is that you look through the list of licence plates and see which ones you recognize; I think the idea is that you watch whatever stuff you would normally watch, and any time one of the licence plates on the list appears you check it off. I think this is also quite an un-PSE-ish mechanic.)

Comment: Thanks everyone. As a fellow mod (from Game Dev), I value keeping the right content on the sites. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

The idea of the puzzles here is you solve them with the information you are given, maybe with a little bit of research. Here, it seems the intent is for the "solving" to not happen directly at all - you'd just notice them while watching something unrelated. Even looking directly would probably just mean reverse image searching, which isn't puzzly, it's trivia.

Thus, I agree with the mods. No, not on-topic for the site

(posted so there's an answer)

Comment: I agree with the reasoning but think "no" is still fundamentally just a judgment call as to whether it qualifies as an acceptable "little bit of research." I would imagine some such license plates will readily show up in a Google search, for example, and from there, the puzzle could be reasonably figured out. Or maybe maybe not, and there is 0% chance of solving the puzzle without researching every frame of every movie in existence. In either case, I think it's a matter of quality, and I let the voting masses determine that quesiton.

Comment: I thought I covered that with "Even looking directly would probably just mean reverse image searching, which isn't puzzly, it's trivia." - if the *entire puzzle* consists of searching images, that's not a puzzle, it's trivia. There is no interesting puzzle element.

Comment: OP will have to clarify if he meant a textual list or a list of still pictures (I interpreted it as the former). In the former case, there is still the puzzling aspect of deducing that they even are license plates, for instance, in fact license plates from famous movies. But if it's not an enigmatic puzzle, that would defeat most of the argument.